# Best practices for initialising Objective-C properties

Tags: objective-c, properties, initialization, conceptual

I understand that this may not necessarily apply to just @properties, but they would be the most common use case. If there is, for example:

```
@property (strong) NSObject *object;

...

@synthesize object = _object;
```

It is possible to initialise it in the `init` method of the class it is declared in like so:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    }
}
```

or override the getter and initialise it upon first use:

```
- (NSObject *)object {
    if (!_object) {
        _object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    }
    return _object;
}
```

Which of these is it better to use? Does this depend on the use scenario (e.g. does the object the property is declared in have multiple initialisers, or the type of the property, how it's used, etc.)?

The real advantage I see in overriding the getter is that the property will only be allocated when it is needed, but a disadvantage would be that the first access would be slower.

On a side note, when accessing properties in the `init` method, is it better to access them as `self.object` or `_object`?

Comment: Make sure to use `if (self) {` in your init method before you start setting properties....

Comment: Oops. Fixed it. Thanks for noticing.
I don't miss it in Xcode, it just wasn't part of what I was talking about here, so I forgot it here while staring at a plain text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

personally i find initializing in the init method is better, the life expectancy of the object is then more clear and also consider if the init fails for the object, isn't it better to get that at the init than when you  do a get?

i also prefer to use `self.object` for properties because it uses the getter and setter of the object and the "self." makes it clear and to avoid situations where a retain is needed or not. sure in some cases like in your example it may cause a couple more lines of code but i rely on the compiler to optimize the code.

e.g.

```
yourobjclass* tmp = [[yourobjclass alloc] init];
self.object = tmp;
[tmp release];
```

Comment: But is there a difference between accessing directly or via property if you are not overriding the accessor?

Comment: I always access the property, but in the `init` method, I read somewhere that it was better to access directly. So I wanted to know.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite one aim with coding is to make your intentions clear for other programmers who read your code, by using the self. prefix you make it clear how the object should be handled, when you don't it may not always be selfevident whether to do a retain or not in all circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to the accepted answer, [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html) says you should use instance variables in the initializers and in the dealloc method. See 'Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc'.

Comment: a lot has happened in 11 years